# Getting imports right in Helper files in IHP

Tags: haskell, ihp

I am trying to centralize some of my view and controller logic into helpers in their respective helper files in `Application.Helper.Controller` and `Application.Helper.View`.

I am finding that I don't have access to the packages I have access to for example in my controller files. Like for example `Data.Text` and lots of others. I stopped trying to import them all when I didn't even have access to the pipe operator.

Same with the `View.hs` helper file does not have access to the `hsx` syntax.

Is there a simple way to fix this? How do you solve this? Must imports be made manually here?

It would seem simpler to me to make Helper files inside the `Web/Controller` folder as the modules inside that folder seems to do the correct automatic imports with no issue.

**My Controller.hs file as it looks now, not supporting stuff like Data.Text and pipe operator:**

```
module Application.Helper.Controller (
    module IHP.LoginSupport.Helper.Controller
) where

-- Here you can add functions which are available in all your controllers

import IHP.LoginSupport.Helper.Controller
import Generated.Types


type instance CurrentUserRecord = User
```

**and the View.hs, that does not support the hsx syntax:**

```
module Application.Helper.View (
    -- To use the built in login:
    module IHP.LoginSupport.Helper.View
) where

-- Here you can add functions which are available in all your views

-- To use the built in login:
import IHP.LoginSupport.Helper.View
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Application.Helper.Controller` you need to import `IHP.ControllerPrelude`, like this:

```hs
module Application.Helper.Controller (
    module IHP.LoginSupport.Helper.Controller
) where

-- Here you can add functions which are available in all your controllers

import IHP.LoginSupport.Helper.Controller
import Generated.Types
import IHP.ControllerPrelude


type instance CurrentUserRecord = User
```

In `Application.Helper.View` you need to import `IHP.ViewPrelude`, like this:

```hs
module Application.Helper.View (
    -- To use the built in login:
    module IHP.LoginSupport.Helper.View
) where

-- Here you can add functions which are available in all your views

-- To use the built in login:
import IHP.LoginSupport.Helper.View
import IHP.ViewPrelude
```

This should propably be added to the IHP project template.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Yes, would be probably be helpful for beginners to have in the template 

Comment: Fixed via https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp-boilerplate/commit/5c98c8b2b99156e6de4e91905fc865c2a84a9942 :)